# How to create and use single-tenant Elastic DB in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database

I want create a Single tenant Elastic DB using C#, can anybody provide a sample beginners code (I found Multi-tenant shard  but I need Single tenant Shard connection). Can you please help me with some sample links?

Comment: A few questions before I start putting up some code for you.  Are you looking for code to create the pool, or the database within the pool? Do you already have your shard map built? Since you're asking about single-tenant, I'm guessing you're trying to build out a services oriented database Architecture (SODA) is that right?

Comment: Hi Shannon thank you for your response , Actually my requirement is each customer have one unique database using single instance .Once they enter their username it will connect to that user respect database , So, i thought single tenant is the suitable thing for me .. but i don't know how to do to start process ..  If i use multi tenant it is sharing the data based on the ranges  that i don't want ..  If i thinking wrong please suggest me.. Thanks

Comment: I think it may be a terminology issue. If you have multiple customers with separate data, then you are dealing with multiple tenants. Each customer is a tenant. When you build your shard map you don't have to create them in ranges, you can do a single identifier. I most often use an integer. I'll start elaborating in an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with some quick terms [and a link from Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-glossary/) I'll be walking you through to get you started in Elastic Databases in Azure.

**Terminology**

- [Database pool](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-pool/) - a container that contains one or more databases that share resources. Hopefully you have a solid measurement for each one of your client database's resource usage. While your pool will have a certain amount of resources allocated to it, if more than 60% of your resources are used by a small subset of your clients, the other clients will suffer a performance hit.
- [Shard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)) - a single database within your architecture. It can be in a database pool, it could be a SQL Azure Database (PaaS), it could be a database on a VM in Azure (IaaS), it could even be an on premise database.
- Tenant - in your case your tenant is your customer.
- [Shard map](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-shard-map-management/) - think of this as your directory for finding a specific customer's data. In your case you want each customer to have a separate shard.
- Shard key - the code that represents each tenant in your system.  You can choose an int, bigint, varbinary, or uniqueidentifier (GUID) as your data type for your shard key
- Data-Dependent Routing - using a shard key to look up where the associated data for that shard key is stored, then connect to that other shard to perform some data task.

**Database Architecture**

Let's dive into your database design and work through how your design can work with elastic databases.

In your current database design you have some way of tracking a user logging in belongs to a specific customer. Some designs handle this by parsing the URL of the login request: https://.someservice.com. Others will have a database to track this email address has access to this (one or more) customer's data. This data isn't directly related to a specific customer, so you're going to have to come up with a way to store this data outside the tenant shards. You may want to store this in the root node (or root shard), possibly the same place you will store the shard map manager.

You may also have tables related to the login - customer map that help you perform some function in your system.  These too would need to move out of the tenant shard and up to the root shard.

If you have referential integrity turned on (as you should), and you have customer specific data with a Foreign Key to a table you're planning to relocate to your root shard, you're going to have to get rid of that constraint.

You'll also have to come up with a method to prevent a login from one customer from affecting data for another customer.  You can not simply leave it to the fact each customer is in a separate database be your control.  In fact, when designing your solution, assume you had an extraordinarily powerful SQL server capable of running all your customers on a single host.  If you do that, then you'll be sure to control access, and prevent that cross-talk problem.

The basic solution is you will now include your shard key (that uniquely identifies each tenant) in every query. That way you are sure of what tenant is being affected by the query.

Now that you have started segregating root node tables from customer tables, let's talk more about the Shard Map Manager and implementing the single tenant per database instance strategy.

**Shard Map Manager**

When you go to build your shard map, you will want to implement a list shard map. As you start adding shards to your map, you'll identify which customer will use each instance, and the shard map will create 4 tables that you can query to find that customer's database connection string.

In the database you will see a max and min shard key value for each shard defined, but when you implement the list, you should only see values in the minimum value. Then each customer gets their separate database.

**Additional steps before getting into the code**
Use the portal to create a pool, even a basic pool.  Then use the portal to add new databases to the pool. Use the portal to move databases into, and back out of the pool.  That's important so you can start planning for those customers where you'll have to move them from PaaS to Iaas Instances to handle their workloads.

You'll also need this pool, and some of those databases for the demo app.

Once you are comfortable with that, [grab the demo app microsoft provides.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-get-started/) When you run the demo you'll see 6 options:

1. Create shard map manager and adda  couple of shards
2. Add another shard
3. Insert sample rows using data-dependant routing
4. Execute sample multi-shard query
5. Drop shard map manager database and all shards.
6. Exit.

Work through the steps one at a time, stopping to read through the code to get a better handle on how these operations are performed.  The good news is with the new sql connection type, a lot of the hard work is performed for you. So long as you have your database and application broken down into units of work that don't try to cross the boundary between the routing data and the customer data.

This is a HUGE topic, and should probably be taken over to the new documentation section on stack overflow to go through these in greater detail.  There are great benefits to this methodology if you're developing a single software solution you want to be able to repackage over and over and start selling your own Software as a Service!